# Занесение фото в MySQL

Tags: mysql, html, изображения, php, sql

Подскажите, какие поля формы и какими функциями `PHP` можно загрузить имя фотографии в `SQL` базу, и скопировать эту фотографию в определённую папку на сервере?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) HTML форма, как минимум

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="uploadfile"/>
<input type="submit" value="Загрузить"/>
</form>
```

2) PHP код upload.php, как минимум:

```
<?php
// Каталог, в который мы будем принимать файл:
$uploaddir = './files/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);

// Копируем файл из каталога для временного хранения файлов:
if (copy($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
{
echo "<h3>Файл успешно загружен на сервер</h3>";
}
else { echo "<h3>Ошибка! Не удалось загрузить файл на сервер!</h3>"; exit; }
?>
```

3) Хранить в базе можно разыми способами:

- Создать в таблице поле 'photo' и непосредственно хранить линк.
- Можно вообще не хранить в базе, а вложить в имя файла определенный ID объекта к которому принадлежит фото, далее уже при формировании Html выдергивать ссылку на фото через этот id
- вариантов много...

p.s. `var_dump ($_POST); var_dump ($_FILES)` поможет при отладке.

Comment: или если хотите поизвращаться, почитайте про тип поля BLOB =)

Answer (score 4):

Прежде чем задавать вопросы, не помешала бы азы выучить и просто погуглить, из за таких потом бочку и катят на целый язык ...
И заканчивать надо отвечать уроками Попова ...

```
<?php
$imageDir = './files/';
$imageName = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
$imageInfo = @getimagesize($imageName);

if (!$imageInfo)
    die('Error: file not picture');
if (!copy($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $imageDir . $imageName))
    die('Error: while copying the file')
?>
```

Проверить не помешает, так же можно добавить проверку на расширение файла типо 
    imageInfo[2] != 'GIF'

Comment: только вместо copy лучше юзать move_uploaded_file

Comment: Да я вообще frond end разработчик, что помню то помню)